# Pine Script select security if it's available

Tags: pine-script

I wanted to code an indicator on trading view that uses data from different exchanges. It works for some tickers. But if an exchange doesn't have the ticker available, the code doesn't work anymore.

My code looks like this for multiple exchanges:

```
var ticker = string(syminfo.ticker)
var Coin = str.replace(str.replace(str.replace(ticker, "USDT", "", 0), "USD", "", 0), "PERP", "", 0)
SelectCoin = Coin
Bitmex_perp_usdt = input.bool(title = 'Use Bitmex USDT Perp Data', defval=true)
Bitmex_Perp_USDT = 'Bitmex:' + SelectCoin + 'USDT'

cum_vol_Bitmex_Perp_USDT_Volume = 0.0
Bitmex_Perp_USDT_Volume    = request.security(Bitmex_Perp_USDT, timeframe.period, volume)
if Bitmex_perp_usdt == true
    cum_vol_Bitmex_Perp_USDT_Volume := math.sum(Bitmex_Perp_USDT_Volume, period)
```

My idea was to ignore the missing tickers with the input, but I can't use request.security in an if statement. Is there a possibility to use request.security combined with a condition? Or at least a way that my code ignores tickers if the input is false? For example, if Bitmex_perp_usdt == false, I don't use request.security or it ignores the error?
I also tried it this way and I still get the same error:

```
var float Bitmex_Perp_USDT_Volume = na
Bitmex_Perp_USDT_Volume := (Bitmex_perp_usdt == true) ? request.security(Bitmex_Perp_USDT, timeframe.period, volume) : na
```

I had another issue with Bitmex, their Bitcoin symbol is 'XBT' and not 'BTC', if I try to fix it like this:

```
Bitmex_Perp_USDT = 'Bitmex:' + SelectCoin + 'USDT'
Bitmex_Perp_USD = 'Bitmex:' + SelectCoin + 'USD'

if SelectCoin == 'BTC'
    Bitmex_Perp_USDT := 'Bitmex:' + 'XBT' + 'USDT'
    Bitmex_Perp_USD := 'Bitmex:' + 'XBT' + 'USD'
```

or like this:

```
var string Bitmex_Perp_USDT = na
var string Bitmex_Perp_USD = na
Bitmex_Perp_USDT := (SelectCoin == 'BTC') ? Bitmex + 'XBT' + 'USDT' : Bitmex + SelectCoin + 'USDT'
Bitmex_Perp_USD := (SelectCoin == 'BTC') ? Bitmex + 'XBT' + 'USD' : Bitmex + SelectCoin + 'USD'
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the request.security function.
```

I can also post my whole code, but I thought that this is enough to understand my problem.

**EDIT**

I fixed the XBT/BTC issue with a function. If anyone else has problems with it, here is how I did it:

```
fix_bitmex_btc(Select_Coin) => 
    return_symbol = Select_Coin
    if Select_Coin == 'BTC'
        return_symbol := 'XBT'
    else
        return_symbol := Select_Coin
```

**2nd EDIT**

I fixed the first issue with a symbol input. If the input is used or not is determined with the bool input. Now it looks kinda like this:

```
Bitmex_Spot_USDT = input.symbol(title = 'Bitmex USDT Spot Pair', defval="SPY")
Bitmex_spot_usdt = input.bool(title = 'Use Binance USDT Spot Data', defval=true)
```

and the rest is basically the same. The issue is kinda fixed, but typing everything manually is a pain in the ass, so if someone knows a way to fix my initial issue, I would gladly hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [request.security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity) has `ignore_invalid_symbol` parameter. You can set it to `true`. If symbol doesn't exist your script continue work.